# SWT ToolItem toggle style

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to create a `ToolItem` on a toolbar, with the `SWT.Toggle` style, but it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: `ToolItem` doesn't even support `SWT.Toggle`: _"Only one of the styles `CHECK`, `PUSH`, `RADIO`, `SEPARATOR` and `DROP_DOWN` may be specified. "_

Comment: @Baz Yeah, figured that out just today. Thought I'd share this on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SWT.Check` instead of `SWT.Toggle` for `ToolItem`s.

---

**[Baz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449199/baz):**
`ToolItem` doesn't even support `SWT.Toggle`: *Only one of the styles `CHECK`, `PUSH`, `RADIO`, `SEPARATOR` and `DROP_DOWN` may be specified.*

Comment: Check will be rendered as Toggle. See getSelection method in http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FToolItem.html